# Java Serial Communications with RS-422

Tags: java, communication

I have been investigating the Java.Comm API and I noticed it provides functionality to TX and RX in RS-422 serial communications. I am looking for a solution for RS-422 serial communications. Does the Java.Comm API provide functionality for RS-422 just as it does with RS-232?

Answer (score 1):

It should work with both RS-422 and RS-232

However, I want to also suggest using [Apache Mina](https://mina.apache.org/) I recently used this library and its robust and easy to implement/test.